# grayscale filter on the (infinite) background image of a div

Tags: css

I want to add a grayscale filter on a background image of a div. This should affect the background only and not the content.

So I set my image and filter in a :before.
This was fine until I tried to scroll the content.
The background image only fills the visible part of the parent.

```
#scrollable
{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  top:300px;
  left:300px;
  overflow:scroll;
  z-index:0;
  color:red;
}

#scrollable:before
{
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7);

    filter: grayscale(80%);
}

<div id="scrollable">foo<br />...</div>
```

I'm looking for a css only answer.

original https://jsfiddle.net/va0qxhth/

Edited:
precision: I need the background to fill the visible part of the parent, no matter the size of the children.

In my real case, the children are hold into a ul/li container

```
<ul class='inner'>
  <li><div>foo</div></li>
  <li><div>foo</div></li>
  <li><div>foo</div></li>
  <li><div>foo</div></li>
  <li><div>foo</div></li>
  <li><div>foo</div></li>
 </ul>
```

so you can use the ul as a inner container as proposed by Amit.

modified fiddle using Amit suggestion https://jsfiddle.net/va0qxhth/3/

This works but I need to add a :before on both the outer container (in case the children are not long enough) and the inner container (to fill the scrollable part of the parent)
I hoped there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: and https://jsfiddle.net/va0qxhth/4/ alike the codepen i linked earlier ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also give a try to [background-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode) :

```css
#scrollable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow:auto;
  color: red;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.8),rgba(255,255,255,0.8)), url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7) local;
  background-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo<br />foo
</div>
```

---

**edit** just noticed your update. from your new code, it could be *(from [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYJVMY) linked earlier)*:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
ul:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7);
  filter: grayscale(80%)
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 200, 0.5);
}
#scrollable {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  /*top: 300px;
  left: 300px;*/
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  <ul class='inner'>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how it works but it works. Too bad it is not supported by IE >= 11

Comment: yep, forgot to mention this, in this case i only see an extra wrapper to be used as a buffer to put the filter element as a sibbling and not a parent in order to not inherit its effects. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYJVMY